# how to get mouse to click specific(s)

Tags: python, mouseevent, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to write a code to control where the mouse clicks. currently, I have the code to press Win + X.

I am trying to figure out what would need to be done in order to have the mouse clicks work accurately despite the screen size/number of screens.

```py
import keyboard
winx = keyboard.press_and_release("windows + x" )
```

As the code stands the current click I need is to click system. I will need to click other things throughout the full code but currently figuring out the best way to click "system" is the goal. I've tried clicking based on the location but because of multiple screens/ the size of the screens this isn't accurate.

Currently looking into how to implement pyautogui's image recognition will update as I go.

Comment: I don't believe pyautgui.locateOnScreen("image.png") will work as it has to be exact and the icons may vary from computer to computer.

Comment: I don't use WIndows for years - what means `"system"` for you? If it is icon in bottom left cornet then maybe you should use size of screen to calculuate position ie. `window_height - 10`. OR maybe you should use system's DPI to use different images for different screens.

Comment: @furas "system" when clicked opens up the system settings. This is where you'd view the 'about' information, or go to things such as renaming the pc, advanced system settings etc.